# Scala/Spark API to add or remove table partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, metastore

I am writing one partition through some external process to the table. Now I want some API to add those partitions to metastore.

I know below sql can be executed as a work arrount

```
Alter table <table_name> ADD PARTTION <PARTITIONS>
```

I am looking for some Scala dataframe API to use.

Comment: Do you want to create a partition only, or you want to sink data into a new partition?

Comment: Partitions do have some files with parquet format. I want some API like above sql to add those partitions to meta store.

Comment: Spark DataFrame API has no concept of Hive (or metastore). The only way to do this would be to run the said sql through HiveContext.